# Error: Unable to obtain debug bridge (android studio)

Tags: android-studio

Despues de descargar y ejecutar el `Android Studio bundle (for Linux)` obtengo el siguente error tras lanzar `RUN(Mayus+F10)`:

> Unable to obtain debug bridge

```
Android Studio 1.5.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He podido solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

abriendo el `sdk manager` e instalando:

- `android sdk tools`.
- `android sdk plataform-tools`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Notas: esta basado en GNU/Linux 64

Comment: gracias!! :**********